# Do we have Standardised Comments?

Tags: discussion, faq, comments

There are times when certain standardised comments are called for.

Here are some examples (the links go to the various sections below, under the Answers):

- [General comments](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments#answer-305)
- Prompting user to accept an answer - *in order to clear the unanswered question list*
- [Problems with comments](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments#answer-304)

  - Answer posted in comments - *Solutions to the question posted in the comments, do not show up in searches*
  - Limiting comments  - *Additional information, that **may or may not** have been requested is posted in comments, rather than as an edit to the question*
- [Poor quality questions](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments#answer-402)

  - Ask a good question
  - Unbounded questions
- [Poor quality answers](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments#answer-393)

  - Short answer - *An answer lacking detail, no explanation provided*
  - Repetition - *No new information, the contents of a previously posted answer is repeated by a different user*
  - Link only answer - *Only a link is provided, with no summary, or content, of the link included*
  - Question posted as answer - ***Another** question, (possibly) related to the OP's question, is posted as an answer*
  - "Me too" answer - *"I **also** have this issue"*
  - Edit to a previous answer - *user posts second answer with additional information, not realising that there is an edit button for their first answer*

*et cetera*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Comments

> ### Question in a comment
>
> Hi and welcome to SE.3DP! Please do not ask new questions in comments. Without wishing to sound harsh, StackExchange is a Q&A site, and not a forum of threaded messages. The reason for this is to aid the search for answers to issues, and provide it in a structured Q&A way. I know that this might seem a pain, but can you repost your question using the [Ask Question](https://x) link at the top of the page? When you repost your new question, please feel free to refer back to this original question using the URL, seeing as it is the reason why you posted in the first place.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi and welcome to SE.3DP! Please do not ask new questions in comments. Without wishing to sound harsh, StackExchange is a Q&A site, and not a forum of threaded messages. The reason for this is to aid the search for answers to issues, and provide it in a structured Q&A way. I know that this might seem a pain, but can you repost your question using the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) link at the top of the page? When you repost your new question, please feel free to refer back to this original question using the URL, seeing as it is the reason why you posted in the first place.
```

> ### Answer in a comment
>
> Comments are not recommended for any of the following: [Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Feel free to post an answer instead. Thanks.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Comments are not recommended for any of the following: [Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment);. Feel free to post an answer instead. Thanks.
```

> ### Limit Comments
>
> It is better to [edit](https://x) your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. All of this information can be edited into your question to make it easier for people to answer your question. If all of the information is contained in one block then people don't have to read all of the comments to discover all of the information. Once all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied & deleted.

**C&P ⎘**

```
It is better to [edit] your question to add information requested in comments, rather than adding more comments. Comments are for helping to improve questions and answers, and are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. All of this information can be edited into your question to make it easier for people to answer your question. If all of the information is contained in one block then people don't have to read all of the comments to discover all of the information. Once all of the information needed to answer the question is contained within it, the comments can be tidied & deleted.
```

> ### *Self*-answered in a comment - Initial request
>
> Did any of the posted answers solve your issue? If so, please mark it as the accepted answer. If not, then either refine your question or please post your comment above (which appears to contain the solution) as an answer, and then mark it as accepted in 48 hours, in order to remove your question from the unanswered queue. Answers are not allowed in comments, and may be deleted. If your answer is posted as an answer then it becomes searchable and may help others with the same issue.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Did any of the posted answers solve your issue? If so, please mark it as the accepted answer. If not, then either refine your question or please post your comment above (which appears to contain the solution) as an answer, and then mark it as accepted in 48 hours, in order to remove your question from the unanswered queue. Answers are not allowed in comments, and may be deleted. If your answer is posted as an answer then it becomes searchable and may help others with the same issue.
```

> ### *Self*-answered in a comment - Second request (citing comment - obviously replacing the `blah blah blah`!)
>
> Hi, could you post your comment `blah blah blah` as an answer (maybe expanding upon it as well, if possible) and mark it as accepted. That way your question will no longer be in the unanswered list. Thanks

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi, could you post your comment `blah blah blah` as an answer (maybe expanding upon it as well, if possible) and mark it as accepted. That way your question will no longer be in the unanswered list. Thanks
```

> ### *Self*-answered in a comment - Final Reminder (also citing the comment)
>
> Hi, ***please*** could you post your comment `blah blah blah` as an answer (and expanding upon it as well, if possible and a photo as <username2> says) and mark it as accepted. That way your question will no longer be in the unanswered list. Thanks. (1) Comments do not show up in searches, (2) Your answer may help someone else (3) As we are a beta site we *really* need to keep the number of unanswered questions to a minimum, if we are to continue as a site (4) You will earn more reputation from votes and accepting your answer. Thanks in advance

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi, ***please*** could you post your comment `blah blah blah` as an answer (and expanding upon it as well, if possible and a photo as <username2> says) and mark it as accepted. That way your question will no longer be in the unanswered list. Thanks. (1) Comments do not show up in searches, (2) Your answer may help someone else (3) As we are a beta site we *really* need to keep the number of unanswered questions to a minimum, if we are to continue as a site (4) You will earn more reputation from votes and accepting your answer. Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 6):

A while ago I found a browser add-on which has canned comments embedded in it. This script was made for Stack Exchange. The name of the add-on is: [AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments). There is a complete write-up on it over at [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/54833), which is SE's site for just this sort of thing.

One of the great things about it is it's completely customizable. I've found since I've been sneaking around here on 3D Printing, it automagically sets the "welcome" note to the current site, as well as if there are custom comments you've added on another site won't show up here. That's pretty kewl in my book. One of the things you could do is to create custom comments within the add-on copied from the other great Answers in this Meta post.

Answer (score 5):

## General comments

Frequently you'll find that you type similar comments, but depending on inspiration and time, the comments differ. It would be an excellent idea to maintain a standard comments reply list on some sort of platform (GitHub, GitLab, community wiki on meta, etc.).

Each standardised comment below is shown in two formats:

1. As *block quotes* for readability
2. As *code formatting*, for ease of copy and paste (**C&P ⎘**)

*Where applicable, replace `<username>` with the actual user name of the poster being addressed*.

Note that an automatic standardized comment already exists for marking a duplicate topic; the system will post a default duplicate comment message for you which you can change within 5 minutes after posting.

There are four sections:

- [General Comments](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments#answer-305)
- [Comments](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments#answer-304)
- [Questions](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments#answer-402)
- [Answers](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments#answer-393)

### Welcome to Stack Exchange

Please use these in conjunction with other necessary/constructive comments - not as a stand alone comment, as these tend to add *noise*

```
Hi <username> and welcome to Stack Exchange!
```

or

```
Hi <username> and welcome to Stack Exchange 3D Printing!
```

or shorter (given the limited number of character) and more precise

```
Hi <username> and welcome to SE.3DPrinting!
```

or even shorter

```
Hi <username> and welcome to SE.3DP!
```

> ### Post to be deleted
>
> Unfortunately your post will be deleted, but please do not let this discourage you. Hang around, [ask a question](https://x), post an answer containing a solution, make some constructive edits and earn some reputation, and with a reputation of 50 you will be able to leave comments. Good luck! :-)

**C&P ⎘**

```
Unfortunately your post will be deleted, but please do not let this discourage you. Hang around, [ask a question](/questions/ask), post an answer containing a solution, make some constructive edits and earn some reputation, and with a reputation of 50 you will be able to leave comments. Good luck! :-)
```

---

#### Note on shortcuts: *Magic links* and Relative paths

It is possible to reduce the length of the comments, so that they fit, by using *shortcuts*. Note that the `[help]`, `[ask]`, `[answer]` and `[about]` tags (in the C&P) expand into *Help Center*, *How to Ask*, *How to Answer* and *Tour* links, respectively - so the entire URL does *not* need to be specified.

For example:

- `[help]`   => [help center](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help)
- `[ask]`    => [How to Ask](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)
- `[answer]` => [How to Answer](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer)
- `[about]` => [tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour)
- `[tour]` => [tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour)
- `[chat]` => [3D Printing Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/)
- `[edit]` => Edit the post link

N.B. `[tour]` and `[about]` are equivalent.

See [comment formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for more information, or *better still*, see the [Complete list of help center magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242306/369403).

Also worthy of mention are *relative links*, so you can skip the *absolute URL* part (i.e. `https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com`). For example:

- `[Ask Question](/questions/ask)` => Ask Question link (at the top of the page)

Just copy the relative part of the URL (to the page that you want to point to) from your browser.

Comment: `[chat]` [chat] ....

Comment: `[answer]` [answer]

Comment: `[ask]` [ask]  ...

Comment: `[help/dont-ask]` [help/dont-ask]

Comment: `[help]` [help]

Comment: `[about]` [about]

Comment: `[tour]` [tour]

Comment: `[edit]` [edit]

Comment: `[Ask Question](/questions/ask)` [Ask Question](/questions/ask)

Answer (score 3):

## Answers

> ### New user, Me too answer
>
> Hi <username> and welcome to SE.3D Printing. SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your answer is more a forum style "Me too" comment to another question where you ask for help to start a discussion. This is not what the answer section should be used for. Please read the [help center](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help), accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu. Please take the [tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) and also have a look at the questions and answers to understand how SE works.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi <username> and welcome to SE.3D Printing. SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your answer is more a forum style "Me too" comment to another question where you ask for help to start a discussion. This is not what the answer section should be used for. Please read the [help], accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu. Please take the [about] and also have a look at the questions and answers to understand how SE works.
```

> ### New user, Thanks answer
>
> Hi <username> and welcome to SE.3D Printing. It is great that the provided answer helped you. However, SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your answer is more a forum style "Thanks" comment to another answer. This is not what the answer (nor comment) section should be used for. Please use the voting buttons instead, as it is votes which drive the community. Please read the [help center](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help), accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu. Please take the [tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) and also have a look at the questions and answers to understand how SE works.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi <username> and welcome to SE.3D Printing. It is great that the provided answer helped you. However, SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your answer is more a forum style "Thanks" comment to another answer. This is not what the answer (nor comment) section should be used for. Please use the voting buttons instead, as it is votes which drive the community. Please read the [help], accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu. Please take the [about] and also have a look at the questions and answers to understand how SE works.
```

> ### New user, answer as comment
>
> Hi <username> and welcome to SE.3D Printing. SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your answer is more a forum style comment to another answer. This is not what the answer section should be used for. Your answer has been converted to a comment.  When you gain enough reputation (50) you will be able to comment directly on an answer. Please read the [help center](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help), accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu. Please take the [tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) and also have a look at the questions and answers to understand how SE works

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi <username> and welcome to SE.3D Printing. SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your answer is more a forum style comment to another answer. This is not what the answer section should be used for. Your answer has been converted to a comment.  When you gain enough reputation (50) you will be able to comment directly on an answer. Please read the [help], accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu. Please take the [about] and also have a look at the questions and answers to understand how SE works.
```

> ### Poor quality - Short answer
>
> Hi <username>, and welcome to SE 3D Printing! Whilst your answer may be technically correct, it *is* lacking detail, and, as such, it has been recommended for deletion, unfortunately. If you could expand it then you may get a more positive response. I would recommend that in addition to reading some highly voted answers to gauge the standard expected, that you take a look at the help section relating to [answering](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/answering) questions, in particular [How to write a good answer](https://3dprinting.com/help/how-to-answer), and take the [tour](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information on how stack exchange works. Thanks :-)

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi <username>, and welcome to SE 3D Printing! Whilst your answer may be technically correct, it *is* lacking detail, and, as such, it has been recommended for deletion, unfortunately. If you could expand it then you may get a more positive response. I would recommend that in addition to reading some highly voted answers to gauge the standard expected, that you take a look at the help section relating to [answering](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/answering) questions, in particular [answer], and take the [tour] for more information on how stack exchange works. Thanks :-)
```

> ### Poor quality - Repetition
>
> Hi and welcome to SE 3D Printing! Whilst your answer may be technically correct, it *is* lacking detail, reiterates a previous answer and, as such, it has been recommended for deletion. If you could expand it then you may get a more positive response. I would recommend that in addition to reading some highly voted answers to gauge the standard expected, that you take a look at the help section relating to [answering](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/answering) questions and take the [tour](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information on how stack exchange works.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi and welcome to SE 3D Printing! Whilst your answer may be technically correct, it is lacking detail, and reiterates a previous answer and, as such, it has been recommended for deletion. If you could expand it then you may get a more positive response. I would recommend that in addition to reading some highly voted answers to gauge the standard expected, that you take a look at the help section relating to [answering](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/answering) questions and take the [tour](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information on how stack exchange works.
```

> ### Poor quality - Link only
>
> Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please [edit](https://x) your answer to explain why it is right. Additionally, we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. [*link only*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/) answers are frowned upon (as links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)) & will be rendered useless if the linked-to content disappears. If you add more context and detail from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Thanks for your answer but we are looking for comprehensive answers that provide some explanation and context. Very short answers cannot do this, so please [edit] your answer to explain why it is right. Additionally, we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. [*link only*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/) answers are frowned upon (as links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)) & will be rendered useless if the linked-to content disappears. If you add more context and detail from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful.
```

> ### Question posted as an answer
>
> Hi and welcome to SE.3DP! Unfortunately, your answer does not answer the question. Without wishing to sound harsh, StackExchange is a Q&A site, and not a forum of threaded messages. The reason for this is to aid the search for answers to issues, and provide it in a structured Q&A way. I know that this might seem a pain, but can you repost your question using the [Ask Question](https://x) link at the top of the page? When you repost your new question, please feel free to refer back to this original question using the URL, seeing as it is the reason why you posted in the first place.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi and welcome to SE.3DP! Unfortunately, your answer does not answer the question. Without wishing to sound harsh, StackExchange is a Q&A site, and not a forum of threaded messages. The reason for this is to aid the search for answers to issues, and provide it in a structured Q&A way. I know that this might seem a pain, but can you repost your question using the [Ask Question](/questions/ask) link at the top of the page? When you repost your new question, please feel free to refer back to this original question using the URL, seeing as it is the reason why you posted in the first place.
```

> ### Clarification comment posted as an answer
>
> Hi and welcome to SE.3DP! Unfortunately, your comment posted as an answer does not answer the question. StackExchange is a Q&A site, and not a forum of threaded messages. The reason for this is to aid the search for answers to issues, and provide it in a structured Q&A way.  Your post may be deleted and converted to a comment, but please do not let this discourage you. Hang around, [Ask Question](https://x), post an answer containing a solution, make some constructive edits and earn some reputation, and with a reputation of 50 you will be able to leave comments.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi and welcome to SE.3DP! Unfortunately, your comment posted as an answer does not answer the question. StackExchange is a Q&A site, and not a forum of threaded messages. The reason for this is to aid the search for answers to issues, and provide it in a structured Q&A way.  Your post may be deleted and converted to a comment, but please do not let this discourage you. Hang around, [ask a question](/questions/ask), post an answer containing a solution, make some constructive edits and earn some reputation, and with a reputation of 50 you will be able to leave comments.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Questions

*Please note that if a user is new and has shown some research effort in composing the question, gently guide the new user in completing the question rather than using some of the statements below. If a question needs some more information or an image, use comments or flag for moderator attention if you don't have enough reputation to post comments. We welcome every new member, but not everybody is acquainted with the SE Q/A style (frequently it is assumed that it is similar to a forum of threaded messages).*

> ### New user, forum style question
>
> Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your question is more
> a forum style question where you ask for help to
> start a discussion. Please read the help section, accessible through the button
> with the question mark at the top right menu.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your question is more a forum style question where you ask for help to start a discussion. Please read the [help] section, accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu.
```

> ### Ask a good question
>
> I would recommend that in addition to reading some highly voted questions to gauge the standard expected, that you take a look at the help section relating to [asking](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/asking) questions, in particular [How to ask a good question](https://3dprinting.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information on how stack exchange works. Thanks :-)

**C&P ⎘**

```
I would recommend that in addition to reading some highly voted questions to gauge the standard expected, that you take a look at the help section relating to [asking](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/asking) questions, in particular [How to ask a good question](https://3dprinting.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information on how stack exchange works. Thanks :-)
```

> ### Unbounded questions
>
> Welcome to SE 3D Printing <username>, but I'm afraid that Unbounded Design Questions are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem, so questions that ask for a list of approaches, a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) or shopping selection are off-topic. We prefer [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Take a look at [How to Ask](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) & [tour](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information on how Stack Exchange works.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Welcome to SE 3D Printing <username>, but I'm afraid that Unbounded Design Questions are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem, so questions that ask for a list of approaches, a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) or shopping selection are off-topic. We prefer [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Take a look at [ask] & [tour] for more information on how Stack Exchange works.
```

> ### Too localised (?)
>
> As it stands this question is unlikely to help future visitors and may get closed as [too localized](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). While it is useful to have all of the background in one place, could I suggest dividing this up into a series of [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). See [Is it ok to ask for opinions?](http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/153/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-opinions/154#154) for more background.

**C&P ⎘**

```
As it stands this question is unlikely to help future visitors and may get closed as [too localized](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions). While it is useful to have all of the background in one place, could I suggest dividing this up into a series of [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). See [Is it ok to ask for opinions?](http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/153/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-opinions/154#154) for more background.
```

> ### Bad fit questions/Questions by new users for closed for other reasons
>
> Welcome to 3D Printing.SE <username>, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Take a look at [How to Ask](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [tour](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [3D Printing question checklist](http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1302/3dprinting-stack-exchange-question-checklist) has good advice on how to write a good question. If you [edit](https://x) your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Welcome to SE.3DP, but I'm afraid that questions like this really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works. Also, the [*3DP* question checklist](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/340) has good advice on how to write a good question. If you [edit] your question to fit our community guidelines we can reopen it for you.
```

> ### Old question, no accepted answer - With multiple answers available
>
> Have you found & fixed the problem? If any of the answers helped you to get an answer to your question or come to your own conclusions then please do vote & accept an answer (using the tick button next to it). This helps us reduce the [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered) & stops the question from being bumped once in a while. If you found another answer (than those already posted), please add that answer (& accept after 48 hours) to share your experience with the community. If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Have you found & fixed the problem? If any of the answers helped you to get an answer to your question or come to your own conclusions then please do vote & accept an answer (using the tick button next to it). This helps us reduce the [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered) & stops the question from being bumped once in a while. If you found another answer (than those already posted), please add that answer (& accept after 48 hours) to share your experience with the community. If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.
```

> ### Old question, no accepted answer - With multiple answers available (alternative)
>
> Hello @[UserName], I noticed your question has been up for a while
> now. Have any of the answers below been able to solve your question?
> If so, would you mind accepting the appropriate answer. If not, what
> is missing so that we may help you further? Also, if you have figured
> it out on your own, you can always answer and accept your own
> solution. Thank you.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hello @[UserName], I noticed your question has been up for a while now. Have any of the answers below been able to solve your question? If so, would you mind accepting the appropriate answer. If not, what is missing so that we may help you further? Also, if you have figured it out on your own, you can always answer and accept your own solution. Thank you.
```

> ### Old question, no accepted answer - If there is only one answer
>
> Have you found and fixed the problem? If so, has the answer below led
> you to the solution? Please vote to accept the answer so this question
> is not bumped up once in a while and can be removed from the
> unanswered question list. You may even add your own solution and
> accept that after 48 hours! If you have not been able to address the
> problem please update your question.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Have you found and fixed the problem? If so, has the answer below led you to the solution? Please vote to accept the answer so this question is not bumped up once in a while and can be removed from the unanswered question list. You may even add your own solution and accept that after 48 hours! If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question.
```

> ### Old question, no answer
>
> Unfortunately, up to now, no answers are given on your question! Have
> you found an answer yourself? If so, you may add your own solution and
> accept that after 48 hours. If you have not been able to address the
> problem please update your question so other people may help you find
> an answer. You can even decide to delete the question. We need to
> reduce the [unanswered questions
> list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered) to graduate
> from the Beta stage.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Unfortunately, up to now, no answers are given on your question! Have you found an answer yourself? If so, you may add your own solution and accept that after 48 hours. If you have not been able to address the problem please update your question so other people may help you find an answer. You can even decide to delete the question. We need to reduce the [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered) to graduate from the Beta stage.
```

> ### Self answered but not accepted any answer
>
> Good to see you solved the problem and took the time to share it with
> us! Please accept your answer so that it does not pop up to the top of
> the queue once in a while. This also will help us reducing the
> [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered).

**C&P ⎘**

```
Good to see you solved the problem and took the time to share it with us! Please accept your answer so that it does not pop up to the top of the queue once in a while. This also will help us reducing the [unanswered questions list](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/unanswered).
```

> ### Multiple questions post
>
> Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your question contains
> multiple questions which makes it more difficult to answer as there
> are multiple answers. Please read the [help] section, accessible
> through the button with the question mark at the top right menu and
> read [ask]. Please split up your question by adding the other
> questions in a separate question!

C&P ⎘

```
Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your question contains multiple questions which makes it more difficult to answer as there are multiple answers. Please read the [help] section, accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu and read [ask]. Please split up your question by adding the other questions in a separate question!
```

> ### Cross-posted question
>
> Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! I
> see that you have cross-posted this question on another Stack Exchange
> site. Cross posting is frowned upon, please see [Is cross-posting a
> question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is
> on-topic for each
> site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).
> Please delete one of copies of the question.

C&P ⎘

```
Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! I see that you have cross-posted this question on another Stack Exchange site. Cross posting is frowned upon, please see [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Please delete one of copies of the question.
```