# Helpful Templates / Help us help you!

Tags: discussion

In conjunction with [Do we have Standardised Comments?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments), we should help new users by giving them Templates to fill out so they can help us help them!

Answer (score 5):

As a little trick: one can add these templates "invisibly" by adding the text between `<!--` and `-->` and turning it into a supposed HTML statement, which then is invisible on the real view but can be edited and easily modified in edit view.

Add the following comment to highlight this:

> Hello [User]. Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading `<!--` and trailing `-->` afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.

**C&P ⎘**

```
Hello [User]. Your question is lacking detail and as such is hard to answer without knowing a couple of things about your printer setup. Please [edit] and fill in the [placeholders] in the template I added and then remove the leading `<!--` and trailing `-->` afterwards. This will turn it visible and help us help you find the actual problem.
```

### Printer and basic settings

The most basic problem when we have to help is, that we often don't know what the setup is. So, we need stuff to help in identifying what the user is actually using. But how does the user know? They could fill out the blanks in this, as these are pretty much readable from the slicer and machine:

> I have a [insert printer make and model] which I use together with [insert slicer here]. I print in [PLA/ABS/PETG/Whatever Material] at [Extruder temperature] °C. [The print bed is set to [Bed Temperature] °C / I don't have a heated print bed]. I use a print cooling fan at [whatever] %. The layer height I set to 0.[x] mm, the line width [line width/extrusion width] from the 0.[x] mm nozzle. The Printing Speed is set to [x] mm/s [for walls and [x] mm/s for infill]. My retraction is [X] mm/off at [x] mm/s.

Invisible template version

**C&P ⎘**

```
<!-- I have a [insert printer make and model] which I use together with [insert slicer here]. I print in [PLA/ABS/PETG/Whatever Material] at [Extruder temperature] °C. [The print bed is set to [Bed Temperature] °C / I don't have a heated print bed]. I use a print cooling fan at [whatever] %. The layer height I set to 0.[x] mm, the line width [line width/extrusion width] from the 0.[x] mm nozzle. The Printing Speed is set to [x] mm/s [for walls and [x] mm/s for infill]. My retraction is [X] mm/off at [x] mm/s. -->
```

Comment: Excellent! A very useful template indeed - it will save a lot of typing, as do the [standardised comments](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303/do-we-have-standardised-comments) Thank you :-)

Comment: I've just realised that *when* these are used, for a *new user*, we might have to tell them to remove the `<>` once they have filed in the blanks - or end up having to remove them ourselves...

Comment: @Greenonline yes, one would.

Comment: I have changed the language within the template to remove the word "terse". Terse has negative connotations in the English language. It generally means "short and rude". If you say an OP's question is "terse", you are basically calling them rude ... In the process, if we really don't mean that, we are the ones being rude.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - good point, well spotted... it'll also need to be removed from the standard comments too, as I think I used it there too...

Comment: @Greenonline - AH! I should have known ... glad you adjusted it! :o)

Comment: @Greenonline apparently, the HTML hiding no longer works :(

Comment: Oh, that's really annoying. Do you know since when it stopped working, and also why it stopped working? Was it due to a change by the SE team? Have you got a link? How did you find out?

Comment: @Greenonline I found by adding it to a question that was little more than a blurb "I can't print!" or such. I suspect it is a change in the code

Comment: Hmmm... If I were you. I would raise a bug on Meta.SE. They've made a lot of changes recently, that negatively impact upon the UX/UI.

Comment: The template doesn't seem to be invisible anymore... see https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/19281/4762 and https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/19280/4762. Shouldn't start and end be `<!--` ... `-->`?

Comment: Fixed with the new code!

Comment: Just a thought... would it be worthwhile making the template in a list format (for readibility)? Or would that make it too complicated?

Answer (score 0):

##### List format

This is the same info as Trish's answer but in a possibly more legible format:

> - I have a [insert printer make and model] which I use together with [insert slicer here].
> - I print in [PLA/ABS/PETG/Whatever Material] at [Extruder temperature] °C.
> - [The print bed is set to [Bed Temperature] °C / I don't have a heated print bed].
> - I use a print cooling fan at [whatever] %.
> - The layer height I set to 0.[x] mm, the line width [line width/extrusion width] from the 0.[x] mm nozzle.
> - The Printing Speed is set to [x] mm/s [for walls and [x] mm/s for infill].
> - My retraction is [X] mm/off at [x] mm/s.

Invisible template version

**C&P ⎘**

```
<!-- 
- I have a [insert printer make and model] which I use together with [insert slicer here]. 
- I print in [PLA/ABS/PETG/Whatever Material] at [Extruder temperature] °C. 
- [The print bed is set to [Bed Temperature] °C / I don't have a heated print bed]. 
- I use a print cooling fan at [whatever] %. 
- The layer height I set to 0.[x] mm, the line width [line width/extrusion width] from the 0.[x] mm nozzle. 
- The Printing Speed is set to [x] mm/s [for walls and [x] mm/s for infill]. - My retraction is [X] mm/off at [x] mm/s. 
-->
```