# Moderating comments on Github/Gitlab

Tags: discussion, comments

Related to [Do we have Standardised Comments?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/303/4762), I happened to stumble upon this link on Github, [Benjol](https://github.com/Benjol)/[SE-AutoReviewComments](https://github.com/Benjol/SE-AutoReviewComments), whilst reading [this comment](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19503/is-it-acceptable-to-copy-other-users-common-moderation-related-comments?cb=1#comment42187_19504) from this question on AskUbuntu's meta site, [Is it acceptable to copy other user's common, moderation-related comments?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19503/348964).

As yet, I am not sure how useful it would be or what we could do with it, but I thought I'd just make it known, if anyone has any ideas (i.e. cloning it for our use; making our own Github (or Gitlab) repository for ours, or; whatever) then post them below.

---

It turns out that Paulster2 mentioned it in [an answer](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/a/315/4762) to [Do we have Standardised Comments?](https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com/q/303/4762), so I haven't discovered anything new, after all.